# SQL query returning null when sent through a program instead of directly

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm building a program that generates a code for the user based on parameters they select.

Essentially, it works by looping through each of the drop down lists they use to select their parameters. One at a time, it pulls the text from a dropdown, inserts it into a standard query, and runs the query. The result is then put into a string, and once all of them have been looped through, it has a completed string, which the user is given.

There are 8 parameters for them to select from. The first 7 work every time. The 8th parameter has an issue only with one specific selection in that dropdown.

Here's the kicker: when the program is running, I put a breakpoint in right before the data is sent to the DB that 8th time. I copy out the query it's about to submit to the DB and run it manually. When I run it manually, it returns the information I want. Then I hit F5 to let the program submit the query, and it receives 'null' back.

I feel like I've tried everything, and other programmers I show it to have no idea what the issue could be.

Any suggestions? Considering the fact that the code works 7 out of 8 times, and that when I run the query manually, it works just fine, I can't see the code being the issue.

EDIT: I'm using SQL server. 
EDIT 2: example code below.

First function

```
private string codeGen ()
{
     string strSearch = "SELECT CODE FROM TABLE WHERE ELEMENT = '";
     string strSQLQueryTerm = "";
     List<string> List = new List<string>(8);

     List.Add(dropdown1.text);
     List.Add(dropdown2.text);
     //etc...
     List.Add(dropdown8.text);

     for(int i=0; i<List.Count; i++)
     {
          strSQLQueryTerm += contactDatabase(strSearch + List[i] + '");
     }

     return strSQLQueryTerm;
}
```

Second function

```
private string contactDatabase(string query)
{
    Object obj = new Object();
    SQLConnection sqlConn = new SQLConection(string.Format(/*login info*/);
    SQLCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn);

    sqlConn.Open();
    obj = SQLComm.ExecuteScalar();
    sqlConn.Close();
    return obj.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Odds are that you have different connections settings. For example, SQL Server has settings that affect the connection which indicate how to handle nulls. You should post which DB server you're using and a sample query that has the problem.

Comment: You'll have to provide us with more info. Show relevant code and/or your query. What type of DB are you using? SQL Server, Access, ...?

Comment: Does the 8th term contain an apostrophe?

Comment: No, the 8th term is just "VT"

Comment: Unrelated (probably) to your issue, but you should be a) using a stored procedure and b) parameterizing your queries.

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but I'd recommend doing a quick read on `using()` and apply that to your code, along with `try catch`.  It would be good to ensure things are disposed of and closed if something unexpectedly blows up.

Comment: Am I reading this right, the query will end up looking like: "SELECT CODE FROM TABLE WHERE ELEMENT = 'value' 'value1' 'value2'" You have no "OR" or/and "AND" keywords...

Comment: @Adam: I haven't made it that far yet ;) I'll put that in once I get this functioning on a basic level.

Comment: @FrancisDucharme - no, each step of the loop builds a `SELECT` statement, then the `contactDatabase` method runs that query and returns the results, which get appended together in one string.

Comment: Try removing (or skipping) the other 7 statements and just running the last (failing) one. (Alternately, just comment out the first 7 `List.Add` calls.) Does it still fail?

Comment: What populates the last drop down list ? Maybe you have a hidden character SQL doesn't like? Visual Studio may be stripping it out when you debug.

Comment: @AdamV: Yeah, it still returns 'Null'.

Comment: @FrancisDucharme: For testing purposes, I just hardcoded it in. Additionally, I've tried changing it to random phrases (in both the program and on the DB, of course) to see if they worked, and it made no difference.

Comment: OK, let's bring out the big guns. Run an SQL Profiler on the database when the program runs.

Comment: Just shooting from the hip here (since it's so odd that it's failing) - what happens if you copy the text from one of the other 7 dropdowns?

Comment: @AdamV: If I copy the text from another dropdown, it works just as it should. Also, everything in the problematic dropdown works except for one selection.

Comment: @DanCallahan The value causing the issue is `VT` ? So, this is being sent to the DB: `SELECT CODE FROM TABLE WHERE ELEMENT = 'VT'`? Are you receiving a `null` or a `DBNull`?

Comment: @Dan I recieve a 'null' back.